# How long is the horizontal stabilizer on a Boeing 737?

Tags: boeing-737

I can never find information about the length of the horizontal stabilizer all I can find is the height of the vertical stabilizer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this Boeing pdf (page 39)](http://www.boeing.com/assets/pdf/commercial/airports/acaps/737sec2.pdf), the total length of the horizontal stabilizer on a 737-800 is 47 ft 1 in.

Comment: Total wingspan or the length of each horizontal stabilizer.

Comment: Total length of the entire horizontal stabilizer. Looking at the diagram, the space between each stabilizer (at the tail) is negligible, so you could divide by 2 for a rough estimate.